# Applescript for iMessage to do a tap back (heart, like, etc) on a message

Tags: applescript, imessage

I'm attempting to use an apple script to write a tap back to like or heart a message by which I know the GUID and ID of and the conversation it's / who sent it.

Does anyone have any ideas how to write it? I am failing.

```
tell application "Messages"
    set messageGUID to "INSERT_GUID_HERE"
    set targetMessage to first message whose guid is messageGUID
    set likedStatus to liked of targetMessage
    end if
end tell
```

Just errors

> 55:62: syntax error: Expected class name but found identifier. (-2741)